# How do I prevent Lazy loading in Ebean using Jackson?

Tags: playframework, jackson, ebean

I have the following scenario:

```
public class ContrivedEntity extends Model {

    private Long id;
    private Shipper shipper;
    private Location location;
}

public class Shipper extends Model {

    private Long id;
    private Country country;

}
```

A ContrivedEntity has several relationships and its relationships themselves also have dependencies...
I created a functionality where the user is able to search Contrived Entities.... This search feature does not need dependencies to be loaded, but when I serialize the results using the play's helper Json.toJson it lazy loads the other dependencies resulting in several other queries...

I have managed to prevent this behavior by using Jackson Views(using annotations in the entities that I would like to ignore in the final result)... 
**but I'm looking for something that could be done on Ebean's end... while composing an EBean query...**

**Is it possible to prevent lazy loading in this manner?
In case of a 'No' answer... Does Hibernate provide such functionality?**
*Any help would be really appreciated...
If you need more context just leave a comment and I will edit the question.*

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to find something as simples as...

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(new Hibernate4Module());
Json.setObjectMapper(mapper);
```

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-hibernate

Thank you for your help

Comment: So you might be looking for: https://github.com/ebean-orm/avaje-ebeanorm-jackson ... but again just note that going off 'is this property loaded' may not work as you'd expect when you also incorporate an L2 cache.  So generally I'd recommend a more explicit approach.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use Ebean's PathProperties and JSON support to do exactly what you want.  Ebean has good JSON support built in and this is one of the reasons for it to do so.

That is, you can use PathProperties to define the properties you wish to include in both the JSON output and query. In current Ebean you use Query.apply(pathProperties) ... to tell the query what part of the object graph to fetch.

An example:

```
PathProperties pathProperties =
        PathProperties.parse("(id,status,name,shippingAddress(id,line1,city),billingAddress(*),contacts(*))");

List<Customer> customers = Ebean.find(Customer.class)
    .apply(pathProperties)
    .findList();

String jsonString = Ebean.json().toJson(customers, pathProperties);
System.out.println(jsonString);
```

Note that Ebean now used Jackson core internally for it's built in JSON support and there is also a Jackson Ebean module in github but not yet released.

It might be good to map Jackson views to Ebean 'pathProperties' but I have not looked at that yet.

Hopefully that helps
Cheers, Rob.

Comment: I was trying to find something more simple to be done... something that could simple ignore Lazy proxies.... 
I will stick with the Hibernate solution

Thanks a lot Rob!

Comment: Ok.  That won't work too well if you start using an L2 cache (which could have partially loaded data) ... but sure.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add an extra alternative. Ebean's Query also now supports disabling lazy loading.

```
query.setDisableLazyLoading(true)
```

So there are currently those 3 options:

1. Query.setDisableLazyLoading(true)
2. PathProperties
3. avaje-ebeanorm-jackson

There is a 4th option I potentially like but it needs time/effort.

Answer (score 1):

> ...but I'm looking for something that could be done on Ebean's end... while composing an Ebean query...

It's not possible, many people would love this feature (me 2), the only sensible way is creating dedicated model class and filling it "manually" with the selected data.

Also using reflections is good way to consider, especially if you have advanced REST api with many different cases.

Comment: Note that this is not the case, there are definitely some existing good options with Ebean. Once you need to take into account partial objects and L2 cache the issue is more interesting and you need to think about it more.

Answer (score 1):

I required a solution to avoid lazy loading by ebean during Json.toJson serialization and came up with this. It is pretty hairy, but it has the virtue of being localized to the model class and working fine with the standard Json.toJson.

Define a generic helper:

```
/**
 * Check if a lazy-loaded property on an ebean model class has been loaded without accidentally loading it
 * @param clazz The class instance of the object to check (T.class)
 * @param bean The actual object to check the property on
 * @param propertyName The name of the property to check
 * @param <T> The class of the object
 * @return Whether it has already been loaded or not
 */
public static <T> boolean isPropertyLoaded(Class<T> clazz, T bean, String propertyName) {
    // avoid ebean lazy loading by using the secret ebean api
    if (bean instanceof EntityBean) {
        // obtain the ebean descriptor of the class and property
        BeanDescriptor<T> beanDescriptor = ((SpiEbeanServer) Oracle.getCurrent()).getBeanDescriptor(clazz);
        BeanProperty property = beanDescriptor.getBeanProperty(propertyName);
        EntityBean eb = (EntityBean) bean;
        EntityBeanIntercept ebi = eb._ebean_getIntercept();
        // is this the simple case?
        if (!ebi.isLoadedProperty(property.getPropertyIndex())) return false;
        // if it is a list, check if it is populated
        Object value = property.getValue(eb);
        if (value instanceof BeanList) {
            BeanList list = (BeanList) value;
            // if it is marked as loaded and is not null
            return list.isPopulated();
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Then on the ebean model class, use it like this:

```
@JsonIgnore
@ManyToMany(fetch=LAZY)
@JoinTable(...)
public List<RelatedEntity> relatedEntities;

// getter used during JSON serialize to avoid ebean lazy loading
@JsonProperty("relatedEntities")
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public List<RelatedEntity> getJsonRelatedEntities() {
    if (Helper.isPropertyLoaded(ThisEntity.class, this, "relatedEntities")) {
        return relatedEntities;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```